# In Battlestar Galactica ('78) War of the Gods Pt. 2, what was found in the wreckage of the ship?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

Ever since War of the Gods pt. 2 was broadcast on ABC, I assumed that what they found in the wreckage of the ship was Iblis' real form. But it just dawned on me now, if that's the case, what is Iblis? Did Iblis take on a new (human) form before the ship crashed? Is that Iblis' body?

I've done some reading and yes, we always knew that what was seen (but not shown on TV in '78) was cloven hooves, but whose are they?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding is that the body in the wrecked ship was supposed to be the corpse of some other demonic entity, very similar to Count Iblis's true form, but definitely dead ever since the crash occurred. Once that body was found, Apollo and Starbuck quickly realized it was a reasonable guess that the survivor of the wreck (Iblis) and the dead entity in the wreck (the cloven-hooved demon) were probably members of the same species who had been travelling together.

Yes, I gather Iblis had used his powers to give himself a human form (or the illusion of a human form, or whatever the case may be) so that he wouldn't scare off the first humans who came along to investigate the wreckage.

I first watched that episode a couple of years ago, and I remember that I too had some doubts about just what the heck they had found inside the ship when they finally went in and looked. I believe the following link takes you to the online resource that clarified some things for me:

The Battlestar Galactica Wiki's entry on [Iblis](http://web.archive.org/web/20161216073424/en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Iblis#The_Mystery_of_the_Crashed_Ship) (specifically the "Mystery of the Crashed Ship" portion of that entry) cites the shooting script and actor Anne Lockhart's description of the body of a dead cloven-hoofed alien resembling a demon within the wreckage.

Comment: I see. When I first saw this (I was 11), I thought that Iblis was on a ship like the BG where they fought back and won, but sacrificed their own ship in the process. When Iblis says "my people", it was unclear if he means his actual people or his followers. But now it makes sense. The Seraphs destroyed the ship and he was the sole survivor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was the Pegasus and Sheba would finally learn of her father’s death. That makes sense because count Eblis told Sheba she would see him again…

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this, or it is just a guess?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the wrecked ship had the incredibly well preserved corpses of lizard Cylons and a message written in their long dried green blood to the effect that: "We trusted Iblis and he betrayed us".  My theory is that Count Iblis made a deal with the lizard Cylons to protect them and then caused the machine Cylons to revolt against and exterminate the lizard Cylons.  A few of the lizard Cylons escaped in a "rag Tag fugitive fleet" and one of the ships crashed on the planet seen in the episode.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076984/board/thread/135340740?p=1[1]

Comment: I can see this as a possibility, since all this has happened before and will happen again.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this, or it is just a guess?